# How do I create a percentage field and a data bar that reflects it?

Tags: powerbi, reportbuilder

Like the title said, I am having some trouble learning Power BI Report Builder. (I hope this is the right place to post about this. if not, please point me in the right direction.)

I have created a sample Power BI Report Builder project using car insurance data. Basically, I want to show a deductible (which is a Measure in my data source, and an identical Field in two datasets), along with a percentage (Calculated Field) and a data bar, divided up by State and City (both fields built into my data source). The Percentage column in the State rows should show what percent of the total deductible in the data comes from each state, and the Percentage column in the City rows should show what percent of the state's total deductible comes from each city. The data bar should reflect the percent column in that row.

Here is a visual representation:

[design mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JRMg.png)

(For the sake of this post, Direct_Claim_Deductible_Recoverable will be referred to as "Deductible".)

I have the Deductible column down. It is simply taking data from the DataSet dataset. The bottom column is taking the total of that data for the specified criteria of Year and City.

The Pct% column should show a percentage as described above, but instead it just takes the Deductible column and divides by 1000.

EDIT: Here is the expression for the Pct% column:

```
=round(((sum( 
Fields!Direct_Claim_Deductible_Recoverable_End_Of_Year.Value) /
Sum (Fields!Direct_Claim_Deductible_Recoverable_End_Of_Year.Value, 
"Percent"))*100),2)
```

The Bar column shows a data bar. In the city columns it is reflecting the Pct% column like it is supposed to. In the State columns, it seems to be reflecting a portion of the highest State total, rather than the grand total.

Here is another visual representation:

[run the report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qTTH.png)

EDIT: Here is a visual of what happened when I followed Mark's advice:
[results with total column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpN5r.png)
(The Total column uses the following formula):

```
=Sum(Fields!Direct_Claim_Deductible_Recoverable_End_Of_Year.Value, 
"Percent")
```

EDIT: Here are some more images:

[the value for the Pct column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLhx5.png)

[the Percent dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofVFP.png)

[And the result still looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYPjk.png)

As explained above, there are two things I want to do here:

1. I want to adjust the Data bar in the State rows to reflect a portion of the grand total, not a portion of the state's total.
2. I want to adjust the Pct% column in each row to reflect a percentage of the grand total, not just the Deductible divided by 1000.

Once these two problems are out of the way, the rest should resolve itself.

Thanks!
Joe

NOTE: I had to use the Power BI and Report Builder tags because this stupid site says I don't have the reputation to create new tags, but the post is about the software PowerBI Report Builder.

Comment: Can you show the query used to calculate the current % in the report?  Understood that this will be a fixed division by 1000, but it will be helpful to see the DAX

Comment: If the name of the dataset is `Percent`, then what you have looks correct, it will divide the amount in the row by the amount in the entire dataset.  So this would divide the city's amount by the dataset's total.  So is this working?  Did you change the formula from division by 1000?

Comment: The formula I posted is what was dividing by 1000. That is why I'm confused.

Comment: Yeh, I don't know what happened there, but you're dividing by `Sum (Fields!Direct_Claim_Deductible_Recoverable_End_Of_Year.Value, "Percent")` now, which is the correct formula.  you might also include that expression as a column to test that the results look correct.

Comment: Just tried that. It gave me a column with the grand total for all years, which is 99,669.71

Comment: I'm not sure what your goal is, but if the dataset has all years, then that's what the sum will be.  If you want it for a given year, you could make another dataset for just that year.  Or if your dataset has a year parameter, you could filter it that way.

Comment: Thanks for your help Mark. I just figured out yesterday that my formula was in fact dividing by that 99,669.71 grand total, and then multiplying by 100 because I told it to. And then because it rounded to two decimal places, it appeared as if it was dividing by 1000 because it was dividing by almost 100,000 and then multiplying by 100.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted  :)

Comment: BUT, all I did was figure out what the computer was doing. I still cannot figure out how to get it to give me a percent of the *subtotal* for each year and/or state.

Comment: Oh shoot, that's what the formula should be doing.  What do the results look like with the corrected formula?  Can you include an image of the report with the current value and total from ` Sum (Fields!Direct_Claim_Deductible_Recoverable_End_Of_Year.Value, "Percent")`?  Please exclude formatting in the formula

Comment: Just edited with the formula and the image.

Comment: This looks correct to me, 1250 / 99669.71 = 1.25% and 500 / 99669.71 = 0.5%.   So I misunderstanding this problem.  What are the expected results?

Comment: The division is correct, but the divisor is not. I want the total column in each state row to be the total for that year, which in this case is 4100. And I want the total column for each city row to be the total for that state. So for the sample result, the total column for each state row should be 4100, and the total column for each row under Utah should be 1250.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways to do this, but I'll suggest two:

1. If possible, do the calculation in the dataset.  If this is a PBI dataset, you can use Dax to do the correct calculation at each level.  If this is SQL, you might add one column for state and one for city and then reference the correct calculation at each level.
2. Assuming the above is not possible, you can do this within the report with multiple datasets.  The more complete answer follows:

**Step 1**

For the main dataset, add a parameter to filter the data by year:
[image]

This will add a dropdown for year in the report:

[image]

Once this is done the state calculation will show a percent of the filtered year for the dataset.

**Step 2**

Add another dataset that sums the data by state.  The city calculation will need to lookup this value.  The report can be configured like this:

[image]

The formulas will looks something like below, adjust for actual names.

State:

```
=SUM(Fields!Direct_Claim_Deductible_Recoverable_End_Of_Year.Value)/ Sum(Fields!Direct_Claim_Deductible_Recoverable_End_Of_Year.Value, "Percent")
```

City:

```
=Fields!Direct_Claim_Deductible_Recoverable_End_Of_Year.Value 
/ Lookup(Fields!State.Value, Fields!State.Value, Fields!Direct_Claim_Deductible_Recoverable_End_Of_Year.Value, "DataSetStateLevel")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mark. (I've been working on other things the last few days so I haven't had much time for this project)

Comment: Here's the problem: Percent is the name of the second dataset. I have just updated it to include the State field, and then I tested it to see if it would work. Unfortunately it did not. The formula for my Total column is the sum of the Deductible field in Percent, while the formula for the Pct column is the sum of the Deductible field in Dataset, minus the sum of the Deductible field in Percent, then multiplied by 100 to create a percentage. (I created the Total column in order to see what the denominator was for the Pct column)

Comment: I'm a little loss with your comment, but if you could update your question with the current issue, that would help.  It's hard to see what's happening through comments.  Is the "Percent" dataset aggregating to the state level?

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. The post has been edited with images.

Comment: The percent calculation needs to be done two different ways: 1-for the state row it should divide by the city/state dataset to get a percent of the grand total, 2- for the city row, it should do a lookup to the state dataset and divide by that.  But there's one remaining problem, lookups only work with one key column, so you if you have multiple years, you either need to filter the datasets to one year or concat() the state and year to look up a given value.   Probably makes more sense to parameterize the dataset for a single year - I can't image the pct making much sense across years

Comment: Hey Mark. Sorry to leave you hanging there, but I need to know what function to use in order to do the lookup. I tried the only one I could find (LookupCube), but I don't think that worked.

Comment: This is the lookup function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-lookup-function?view=sql-server-ver16  You can also google for examples of it in use